# Liferay Dynamic QuickLink

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, liferay, liferay-7

I need to implement a dynamic Quick Link in Liferay(a specific user can add or remove only the links he wants to see).
Because I'm not an expert in Liferay Front end and in general in Front-End,

Could someone, please, how to implement in a jsp a dynamic QuickLink? 
And could someone tell me how Liferay customize a page for different user?
How Liferay (7.0) memorize the personalization for each user?

Many thanks.

Kind Regards.

Comment: I'm voting to close here, because the question is a) too broad, b) asking for tutorials (two canonical reasons to close a question on stackoverflow) and c) you've crossposted on the Liferay forum anyways, which [is discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/why-is-cross-posting-wrong-on-an-external-site).

Comment: Hi Olaf, 
I'm not expert as front end developer. I tried to search any tutorials on how to create a dynamic quicklinks, but if you can send me any link, I would appreciate your help. I wrote even here because until now I didn' t have the help I hoped to receive, about other questions (as a not expert in Lifeary) in Liferay community. I thought here more people could give more different tips.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Liferay 7 has audience targeting plugin in the marketplace for the EE version. Please look into it as an option if you have the LR 7 EE. We use audience targeting to personalize our users experience based on which user segment they fall into. This has worked well for us. Fady Hakim has good youtube videos to help you get an overview of the Audience Targeting if you need that.